# How to factor the polynomial $24x^2y - 16x^3y^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

So for this question $24x^2y - 16x^3y^2$ I know the common factor between the two is 8 but Im not sure what to do next?

Comment: nope @uniquesolution

Comment: Just take out the common factors.

Comment: .$8x^2y(3-2xy)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pratyush in the comment and Anikets answer shows **one way** to factor the polynomial, but there are many ways, another is

$$8x(3xy-2(xy)^2)$$

Multivariate polynomials just do not have any unique division algorithm. There is a whole branch of mathematics called algebraic geometry devoted to factoring polynomials and investigating equations and systems of equations of multivariate polynomials.